# How to filter WordPress search, excluding post in some custom taxonomies?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, search

I want to filter WordPress search (and also WordPress listing of posts) on 2 values of a custom taxonomy.

I tried this code, filtering my custom taxonomy named "marque", excluding 70 or 67 IDs (nb : in my back-office, posts can only be classified into one term of my taxonomy a time) :

```
// Filtering on listing
function filtre_listes( $query ) {
    if ( !is_admin() ) {
        $query->set( 'marque', '-70,-67' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filtre_listes' );

// Filtering on searches
function filtre_recherches(&$query)
{
    if ( $query->is_search && ( !is_admin() ) )
        $query->set('marque', '-70,-67');
    return $query;
}
add_action('parse_query', 'filtre_recherches');
```

But it doesn't seems to work. I use WordPress 3.0.5.

Any idea ?

Thanks a lot, and sorry for my approximative english !

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$tax_query = array(
    'relation' => 'AND',
     array(
        'taxonomy' => 'marque',
        'terms' => array( 70, 67 ),
        'field' => 'term_id',
        'operator' => 'NOT IN'
      )
 );
 //turn it into a WP_Tax_Query object...
$tax_query = new WP_TaxQuery($tax_query);

$query->set("tax_query", $tax_query);
```

Comment: Thank you a lot :)

Have I some problems because of 3.0.5 version of Wordpress ? that's why I tried to use a classical syntax.

Is "tax_query" filter not working only with 3.1+ versions of WP ?

Comment: De rien. (Mon francais et tres approximatif.)

Comment: i'm loving your franglais.  is this meant to be used with the pre_get_posts() function?  it is giving me the error that the Class 'WP_TaxQuery' is not found

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude Posts in a Taxonomy Term from appearing in search results, archive lists and more by using the incredibly powerful [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.

Consider the following example placed in your theme's `functions.php` file:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function ( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() ) {
        return;
    }

    // Exclude Terms by ID from Search and Archive Listings
    if ( is_search() || is_tax( 'marque' ) ) {    
        $tax_query = array([
            'taxonomy' => 'marque',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => [ 67, 70 ],
            'operator' => 'NOT IN',
        ]);

        $query->set( 'tax_query', $tax_query );
    }
}, 11, 1 );
```

This action will exclude your terms (67, 70) in the given the taxonomy (marque) from appearing in any search results or archive lists.

Since the `$query` object is passed by reference, we do not need to declare globals or return a value. Thus, any changes made to the object from inside our function are made to the original immediately.