# Theres a way to use $query->set('tax_query' in pre_get_posts filter?

Tags: pre-get-posts

Theres a way to use `$query->set('tax_query', ...)` in `pre_get_posts` filter? for example next code is not altering the query. Note that I'm building $taxonomies from and custom search.

```
function custom_search_filter($query) {
        ...

        // array('taxonomy' => 'category', 'field' => 'id', 'terms' => array( 41,42 ), 'operator' => 'IN')
        $taxonomies = implode(',', $taxonomy_arr);

        // https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25076/how-to-filter-wordpress-search-excluding-post-in-some-custom-taxonomies

        $taxonomy_query = array('relation' => 'AND', $taxonomies);

        $query->set('tax_query', $taxonomy_query);
    }

    return $query; 
}


add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'custom_search_filter', 999 );
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are you passing a `WP_Query` object into an argument setting method?

Comment: Yes i was wrong, now i got it using eval to convert the string into an array (and im really sure that the string is safe). Thanks.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The `$query` variable in the filter represents a `WP_Query` object, so you shouldn't be passing a new `WP_Query` object into the method for setting that object's properties.

The [question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/25076/how-to-filter-wordpress-search-excluding-post-in-some-custom-taxonomies) you copied code from was incorrectly using the action, which may have been the crux of your issue.

Yes, [`tax_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters) can be used inside a `pre_get_posts` action or similarly by hooking `parse_request`, `request` or `parse_query`.

**Here is an example:**
Specify a custom taxonomy for search queries

```
function search_filter_get_posts( $query ) {
    
    if( !$query->is_search || is_admin() )
        return;
    
    $taxquery = array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'career_event_type',
            'field' => 'term_id',
            'terms' => array( 35, 19, 6 ),
            'operator'=> 'IN'
        )
    );
    $query->set( 'tax_query', $taxquery );
    
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'search_filter_get_posts' );
```

Although it should be noted more specificity with your conditional parameters might help in avoiding making alterations to queries you do not intend to.

For example, if you are utilising a custom search form to search on a custom post type, including a hidden field(or even a select box) to set the `post_type` would help out with providing extra conditional specificity.

```
<input type="hidden" name="post_type" id="post_type" value="my_post_type" />
```

The above example `pre_get_posts` (or equivalent) action/filter would then have more information to validate we're modifying the right kind of request/query.

```
'my_post_type' === $query->query['post_type']
```

or

```
'my_post_type' === get_query_var( 'my_post_type' )
```

You could go further and use a query var parameter you're not otherwise expecting in the search query that Wordpress supports, just to act a flag for your action/filter.

```
<input type="hidden" name="author_name" id="author_name" value="my_special_guy" />
```

This provides another conditional parameter for your action to look for, and you can simply unset the value before it reaches the query.

```
set_query_var( 'author_name', '' );
```

Comment: could you give a working example of setting the tax_query inside a pre_get_posts action?

Comment: $tax_query is an object that contains a nested array. You can't override the object with a nested array.

Comment: `$tax_query` is not an object, `$query` is though(it's an instance of `WP_Query`).

Comment: doesn't this completely override the tax_query? shouldn't $taxquery be appended to the current data in the tax_query arg?

Comment: @hot_barbara as it stands, it would overwrite the tax_query. This version would append the current query instead: 
    $taxquery = array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
         array(
             'taxonomy' => 'career_event_type',
             'field' => 'id',
             'terms' => array( 52 ),
             'operator'=> 'NOT IN'
        )
    );

Comment: @t31os
Shouldn't the values of the array key "field" be "term_id" instead of "id"? According to https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#taxonomy-parameters, the possible values are 'term_id', 'name', 'slug' or 'term_taxonomy_id'. The default value is 'term_id'. The value 'id' does not appear there at all.

Comment: It certainly should have been, i've updated the answer to make some corrections/additions.

Answer (score 5):

Tax queries require you to also set the tax_query object in the query since the query has already been parsed. See my answer for [Modify Taxonomy pages to exclude items in child taxonomies](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/43181/modify-taxonomy-pages-to-exclude-items-in-child-taxonomies/98143#98143).