# Taxonomy On Index Page

Tags: functions, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, advanced-taxonomy-queries

I cannot find the way to show my "taxonomy in the index", i don't know how i can display the post, not by default , if not for my taxonomy. Anyone can help me?

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_post', 'my_get_post' );
function my_get_post( $query ) {

    if( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'portafolio' ) );
    }

    return $query;
}
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35196/theres-a-way-to-use-query-settax-query-in-pre-get-posts-filter I think this will help you

Comment: What do you mean by "show your taxonomy in the index"?

Comment: Hello, what I want is to show a taxonomy created by me in the index, I do not want to show the posts by default, as wordpress does